# Listener to load Microsoft Bing Maps equivalent to google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function);

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, bing-maps, dom-events

I usually load Google Maps until the divs that will work as the map canvas are fully loaded, otherwise it won't charge correctly.

I use **google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function);** where function initilizes the Google map and other parameters I need. Until the **DOM element window** fully loads, I initialize the map, avoiding creating the map in a div that still doesn't exists.

My question is which Microsoft Maps events does the same. **Microsoft.Maps** uses  **Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler** to listen events, but there is no event to wait **DOM window** to load (or probably there is one and I'm just missing it). If not, how can I achieve this objective?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just waiting for `window` to load, why not use the native [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)?

```
function load() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "application/javascript";

    // GetMap function will be called when Bing Maps script is downloaded, so inside there initialize your map and other params
    script.src = "http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=[YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY]";

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = load;
```

Answer (score 0):

Map detection was supported in the older version of Bing map (v6.3 or v7). But Bing Map v8 control does not have load method.

But there is one another way to detect Bing map is loaded or not by using Custom Overlay.

> Custom Overlays are a child of the map control, so it can't be loaded
>   until the map DOM is loaded itself.

Here is a sample code that will detect bing map load. Please check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c5cb202-e7da-43bb-bd11-e65539bec205/v8-control-detect-fact-of-fullyloaded-map?forum=bingmapsajax) for more details.

```
<div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:800px;height:600px;"></div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=[Bing Map Key]' async defer></script>

function GetMap()
{
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {});     
    var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), null);
    map.entities.push(pushpin);

    //Create a temporary custom overlay.
    var SplashScreenOverlay = function () {
    }
    //Set prototype to sub-class CustomOverlay
    SplashScreenOverlay.prototype = new Microsoft.Maps.CustomOverlay();

    SplashScreenOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {
        //Need to add something to the DOM so we can track when it gets added to the map.
        this.setHtmlElement(document.createElement('div'));
    };

    //Implement the onLoad method to perform custom operations of rendering the DOM element
    SplashScreenOverlay.prototype.onLoad = function () {
        //Map should be fully loaded at this point, remove spalsh screen.           
        alert('map loaded')

        if(self.onLoad){
            self.onLoad(map);
        }           
        map.layers.remove(this);
    };

    map.layers.insert(new SplashScreenOverlay());
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.